# Parametrized permutation function

Tags: functions, permutations, algorithms

I'm looking for a way to construct a function that would work the way depicted in the following picture:

[image]

That is, I want it to **permute** the elements in a given array to put them in some **different order** depending on a **parameter** I give it, so that the numbers of my choice from the original set (those I marked with grey background) would all end up as a continuous range at the beginning of the output array (to the left of the thick line), while all other elements (red background) would end up at the remaining positions in that array (to the right of the thick line).

The order of those elements in each of the output ranges (grey or red) doesn't matter to me. They can be put in any arbitrary order by that function, whatever is simpler to compute for a particular choice of selected input elements (grey). The only thing that matters is that all those selected elements (grey) end up on one side of the boundary, while other elements (red) end up on the other side of that boundary, and the two ranges are continuous.

This function needs to be **parametrizable** so that, out of all possible permutations of this array, I could choose that particular permutation that puts the elements in that particular order by just specifying some numerical parameter (or parameters) in the function's formula.

One numerical parameter is preferable, since there is only one permutation that puts all the elements in this particular order, and this number could be the "identifying number" of that permutation, but if that would be hard to achieve, several numerical parameters is acceptable, as long as it doesn't exceed the number of chosen elements (which would probably make it not worth the effort anyway).

**Is there a way to construct a formula for such a function in a systematic way, given a subset of "chosen elements" from the input array?** Maybe something based on modular arithmetics or finite fields? A quick web search gave me a term called "permutation polynomials" that at first glance seems to be related to this problem somehow, but all the resources I could find about them are some thick math that seems to require a lot of background in that field to even understand what's going on (I'm just an IT engineer / programmer looking for a solution for some programming problem, not a professional mathematician :q )

Of course, any function could be put into a lookup table. But that's not what I'm looking for, because that would require a lookup table of the same size as the entire input set, which would be an overkill.

**Edit:**
One thing that comes to my mind is modular exponentiation, since in prime moduli, when a primitive root is chosen as the base, and the exponent is our $x$, then every power of that base is unique (maximal period) and the resulting sequence is some permutation of the original sequence (however, it always starts and ends with 1, and there's always $N-1$ in the middle). But this way I can only obtain *some* permutations, not *every possible* permutation.
Raising this exponential function to some other power $p$ only selects every $p$th element from this sequence, so this way I can only get a sequence for another primitive root (provided that $p$ is coprime to the size of the modulus less one, because otherwise the period breaks into shorter cycles, like for some other base that is not a primitive root). Maybe there is some other way to shuffle those numbers than exponentiation?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the parameter is supposed to specify. Does it specify which elements are the selected ones?

Comment: The parameter just specifies which permutation out of all possible permutations is being used. I assumed that even if the function can be parametrized with multiple parameters, each such combination of parameters could be mapped to the some single number identifying this particular permutation, so it is the permutation identifier that really selects one particular function from this family, and can be used to parametrize it instead. However, there can be multiple constants in the formula of that function that can parametrize the formula.

Comment: Also, there is only a subset of permutations that send my numbers of choice to those first positions in the output array (namely the number of possible permutations of those elements in the gray subarray), and all of them are OK, because the order doesn't matter to me. So *any* permutation that sends those "selected numbers" to the first positions in the output array is fine to me. I.e. there can be many different parameters that do the job.

Comment: So in a way, this parameter does specify which elements are selected (in fact there might be many such parameters possible for a certain subset of selected elements), because only those parameters send my chosen elements to the initial positions in the output array. Others don't. Therefore, after I have my subset of elements chosen, I would then like to have a way of finding a parameter that does it (sends my chosen elements to the head of the output array), one parameter for any subset of chosen elements that I would need to select, with the same general formula, just different parameters.

Comment: The Handbook of Finite Fields ( https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Finite-Fields-1st-Edition/Mullen-Panario/p/book/9781439873786 ) is a great source for theory of Finite Fields, first, because it introduces the reader to basic concepts, expanding it to number theory, computational linear algebra, cryptography, engineering, combinatorics, algebraic geometry etc. Another interesting book for introducing yourself to Group-Theory is https://books.google.es/books/about/A_Course_in_Group_Theory.html?id=2jBqvVb0Q-AC&redir_esc=y which is a brief book having necessary concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out. I've read "Visual Group Theory" by Nathan Carter, it's a very good book too, easy to follow, with many good illustrations. Yesterday I also found "Finite Fields" by Rudolf Lidl - is it any good?

Comment: The book of Rudolf Lidl is considered a recommended reading as it covers the fundamental theory. The book I mentioned is partly based on this one, but I find it more complete and interesting since it carries a long list of references to books and articles.

Comment: I wonder what you are trying to gain here. Note that there are $2^n$ different subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and only $n+1$ of them can be served by the same permutation, so your set of parameters should be equivalent to a binary string of length at least $n-\log_2(n+1)$, i.e., the storage space for it is essentially $n$ while the storage space for the trivial representation of the permutation is $n\log_2n$. If the factor $\log_2n$ is crucial, we can think of it, but then the processing time hits. Retrieving from an address up to $n$ is $c\log_2n$, so you do not want it to increase much, right?

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, an invertible (non-singular) $n\times n$ matrix having entries over $F_q$, where q=$p^k$ and $p$ prime defines a finite image space, thus it's a permutation of $F_q^n$. This is, given $M \in GL_n(q)$ where $q=p^k$ and $k\geq 1$, as $M$ is non-singular, it defines a permutation over the tuples in $F_q^n$. This is a consequence of $M$ being an element of the general linear group (invertible matrices) and matrix multiplication being reduced modulo $p$ or $f(x)$ if $F_q$ it's an extension field of degree $n$.

You mentioned Permutation Polynomials over Finite Fields containing $q$ elements. It results that the group of **Linearised** Permutation Polynomials over $F_{q^n}$ under composition and the group of invertible Matrices over $F_q$ under multiplication are isomorphic. A Linearised Polynomial over $F_{q^n}$ can be defined as $p(X) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha_i x^{q^i} \; \alpha_i \in F_{q^n}$ and we have some mathematic ways to prove if it's a Permutation Polynomial or not.

First, explain the relation between polynomials of degree $n-1$ over $F_q$ and vectors-tuples over $F_q$ of dimension $n$. The map $\varphi$ sends a vector to a polynomial and vice-versa:

$$\varphi : F_q^n \mapsto F_{q^n}$$
$$\varphi(a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}) \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i$$

Now, to establish a relationship between invertible matrices over $F_q$ and Linearised Permutation Polynomials over $F_{q^n}$, we must define the map $\phi$ that sends a Linearised Polynomial $p(X)$ to an invertible matrix $M_{p(X)}$.

$$\phi: \mathcal{L}_n \simeq GL_n(q)$$
$$\phi(p(X)) \mapsto \{\varphi^{-1}(p(\varphi(e_1)),\ldots, \varphi^{-1}(p(\varphi(e_n)))\}$$

Clearly, both maps are linear and agree on the same image by applying $\varphi$ to the input of $p(X)$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ to it's output.

$$M_{p(X)}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i = \varphi^{-1}(p(\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi(\alpha_i e_i)))$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n  M_{p(X)} \cdot \alpha_i e_i = \varphi^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n p(\varphi(\alpha_i e_i)))$$

---

In terms of computer science, you don't need to compute Linearised Permutation Polynomials, instead, you can work with invertible square matrices over a prime field, or an extension field of such field. Why? Well, it's been proved that Linearised Permutation Polynomials over $F_{q^n}$ and Invertible Matrices over $F_q$ define an equivalent action by the relationship exposed above. These matrices are elements of the general linear group $GL_n(q)$. This definition, guarantees that, given an invertible matrix $M$ over $F_q$, the operation $M \cdot x = b$ permutes $x$. As a consequence, here multiplication defines a bijection on the set of elements of $F_q$.

---

There is more work under the branch of combinatorics. For example, the symmetric group on $n$ symbols $S_n$ is comprised of all the permutations of degree $n$. From here, you can calculate the $k$th permutation of a set $S$ having $n$ elements by the decomposition into the Factoradic Number System, which gives you a quotient list that defines that $k$th permutation. Another point, is the one you mentioned, which is based on modular exponentiation. For that, understand that having a big order $r$ s.t $g^r \equiv_p 1$ is satisfied it's quite unpractical for permutations, since you must calculate each image $g^i$ until $g^r$, which is bounded by the length of your set $S$ which is going to be permuted.

Comment: Now tell me what books do I need to read to understand all of this, because so far I understood nothing :o  This is even heavier unintelligible math than what I saw so far...  That's why I specifically said that I'm just an IT engineer, not a professional mathematician with a PhD in abstract... whatever the hell this is :q

Comment: What does it mean that a matrix "defines a finite image space"? (So far I got that you're talking about a *square* matrix whose elements are taken from a finite field $F$ with $q$ elements.) And what is the purpose of that matrix in this entire arrangement?

Comment: What I mean is that an invertible $n/times n$ matrix with entries over $F_q$ has clearly rank $n$ thus it has dimension $n$ by the rank-nullity theorem. This is, its image has dimension $n$ thus $q^n$ distinct vectors are obtained by $Mx=b$